# Synchronous and parallel web requests, both receives B bytes per second

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous

Given a bunch of synchronous web requests, executed sequentially - it will take `N` seconds to complete the web requests, and receiving `B` bytes per second. However doing the exact same, but using asynchronous web requests, which makes it possible to execute all of the web requests in parallel - it will no longer take `N` seconds, however it will still receive `B` bytes per second.

Running a simple test, with 12 web requests - using both the synchronous and parallel approach, confirms that they both receive `B` bytes per second (using `Resource Monitor`).

My question is therefore... should the approach that executes the web requests in parallel, not receive more than `B` bytes per second, in order to make up for that it's faster than the synchronous approach? - Else the synchronous approach will both run longer, AND receive more bytes (totally) than the parallel approach.

Comment: How is this implemented? And why do you say that the sync approach would receive more bytes total? If you execute the same requests (assuming the server returns the same data) your responses should be the same regardless of how you fetch them. Behind the scenes all web requests are async, the framework just hides the complexity if you ask for that.

Comment: @xxbbcc, Lets say an application that makes sync web requests, takes 40sec to go through them, and fetch their response. In these 40sec the `Resource Monitor` shows that it receives 500 Kbps. Doing the same with an application that makes async web requests, and finishes in 5sec, the `Resource Monitor` shows that it also receives 500 Kbps. - Calculating the total bytes received: Sync(40sec * 500 Kbps) | Async(5sec * 500 Kbps). From my perspective, that means the sync version have received more bytes than the async.

Comment: There is a **big** difference between asynchronous and parallel. If your asynchronous requests are all run in the same thread, they will run sequentially, regardless.

Comment: @jpaugh, Touché. Replace "async" with "parallel async" in my previous comment.

Comment: @ebb You should use Fiddler to measure the actual number of bytes received. I don't know how accurate that 500 kbs measurement is but if your server returns the same response for a given request then the size should be the same, regardless of how you get it.

Comment: @ebb I just meant, are you *sure* that you're getting parallel web requests? Or is your framework lying to you? Have you logged the tpc stream(s) and seen that the requests are actually handled in parallel?

Comment: @jpaugh, Whether they _really_ are running in parallel, I'm not aware of. - Either way, firing up some async web requests, finishes faster than doing it sync. - But the async approach, still receives the same number of bytes as the sync approach, although the sync approach takes longer time.

Comment: @ebb That's exactly how it should be. Async is faster because multiple requests are handled at the same time. Number of bytes should be the same for both.

Comment: I'd expect it to receive the same number of *bytes*. However, the *bytes/second* would be lower by definition.

Comment: @xxbbcc, So in short, the effective throughput is bytes/sec * parallel calls?

Comment: @jpaugh That's why I wouldn't use Resource Monitor. Who knows what's exactly measured by it or how it's calculated. Fiddler shows the exact data.

Comment: @jpaugh, Yes - the sync approach should receive lower _bytes/second_ than the async approach. - But it's not. They're receiving the same _bytes/second_.

Comment: @ebb I'd calculate it backwards, yes. If you have _N_ total bytes in time _T_ then you have _N_ / _T_ bytes per second.

Comment: @xxbbcc, I see. Guess you cant really trust `Resource Monitor` then. It doesn't seem to take that into account. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @ebb I won't post it as an answer because I don't know it as a fact so I don't want to mislead anybody with that. But I did a lot of performance measurements over HTTP and Fiddler seems to be a reliable tool to use. You can look at all the responses and get fairly accurate timing and that gives you your throughput. Resource Monitor may measure more than just the HTTP request / response data.

Comment: @ebb That implies that the async test case is receiving *fewer* bytes, total. Either your test cases are different, or the server managed to save a few bytes by keeping the connection open longer, etc. Or, that they ran for the same amount of time. Or that your measurements are off. Mathematical laws must not be violated.

Answer (score 0):

These requests are not processed on your machine (unless connecting to localhost). This means that for each request to be fully processed, your machine will have to wait for a response.

Consider sending an invitation for your birthday party to friend #1, and after receiving a response, send one to friend #2, etcetera. It would be faster to send the invitation to all friends, and then wait for all of them to respond. Especially if friend #1 happens to be on holiday.

I don't know why the number of bytes per second are identical, perhaps some node in the network limits the speed, but the parallel approach can at least send out each request and "parallel out" the total wait time.

I don't understand how the synchronicity could affect the total number of bytes received. You're talking about bytes/second, but not the number of seconds spent at that transfer speed.

Comment: I can't really think of anything, that could limit the speed. Beside that, I mentioned synchronicity, because I found it odd how it seemed the synchronous approach would receive more bytes than the parallel asynchronous approach (it takes longer, and receives same bytes/second).